# How to put a static JSON in TreeStore in extJs

Tags: javascript, json, extjs

I am trying to put a JSON in my treeStore .

ExtJs Version - 4.0.7

JSON i am having ::

```
var output = [{"name":"2","children":[{"name":"2.1","children":[]}]},{"name":"Accessories","children":[{"name":"Bracket","children":[]},{"name":"Clamp","children":[]}]},{"name":"Actuator","children":[{"name":"Accessories","children":[{"name":"Bracket","children":[]}]}]}]
```

Code ::

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
    proxy: {
        type: 'memory',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            id:'text'
        }
    },
    root: {
            expanded: true,
            children: []
        }

});



var rootNode = store.getRootNode();
rootNode.appendChild(JSON.stringify(output));

Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
    title: 'Simple Tree',
    width: 200,
    height: 150,
    store: store,
    rootVisible: false,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `name` to `text` in the JSON string.  Also, you do not need to call `JSON.Stringify`: `rootNode.appendChild(JSON.stringify(output))` should be `rootNode.appendChild(output)`.  Also, instead of `children:[]` in your JSON string for the leaf nodes, you can use `leaf:true` as this will display correctly in the treepanel.

See fiddle [here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1pov)

Comment: Thanks for such a quick reply...   [{"text":"2","children":[{"text":"2.1","children":[],"id":"2.1_ID"}],"id":"2_ID"},{"text":"Accessories","children":[{"text":"Bracket","children":[],"id":"Bracket_ID"},{"text":"Clamp","children":[],"id":"Clamp_ID"}],"id":"Accessories_ID"},{"text":"Actuator","children":[{"text":"Accessories","children":[{"text":"Bracket","children":[],"id":"Bracket_ID"}],"id":"Accessories_ID"}],"id":"Actuator_ID"}]... This is what i am having now.. but still i am unable to populate the tree

Comment: This should work.  Did you try putting your new JSON string into the fiddle mentioned above?